# Change a list of maps into a formatted string in terraform

Tags: terraform

I'm trying to set up a Google Cloud Load Balancer and one step requires updating the named ports on the managed instance groups for which I need a formatted string to generate the command-line call. I feel like this should be something that I can automate with terraform, but I'm struggling with mapping data formats.

I have two sets of source data.

From the instance group resource:

```
data "google_compute_instance_group" "all" {
  count = "${length(var.backend)}"
  self_link = "${element(var.backend, count.index)}"
}
```

I get the existing named ports from `data.google_compute_instance_group.all.*.named_port` in the format:

```
[
    [
        map[name:https port:30443],
        map[name:http port:30080]
    ],
    [
        map[name:https port:30443],
        map[port:30080 name:http]
    ]
]
```

I also have the ports that I want to make sure are defined in my own map:

```
variable "node_ports" {
  type    = "map"
  default = {
    "https"   = "30443"
    "monitor" = "30012"
  }
}
```

There may be overlap between these; I want to select the value defined in the variable. (The named ports are the same for all instance groups.)

First, I want to combine the two maps into a single map to make sure that there is one port for each name. How can I convert the first list of lists of maps to a single map so that I get this?

```
{
  "http"    = "30080"
  "https"   = "30443"
  "monitor" = "30012"
}
```

Second, I want to convert all of that to the format needed on the command line:

```
gcloud --project ${var.project} compute instance-groups set-named-ports ${basename(var.backend[count.index])} --named-ports=https:443,http:30080,monitor:30012
```

I think I could do that with a `jsonencode` hack but I'd be interested in better solutions:

```
"${replace(jsonencode(named_ports), "/[\\{\\}\"\\s]/", "")}"
```

Answer (score 2):

I was able to use a for expression to rearrange the list of list of maps using terraform 0.12.x. To break down this statement

```hcl
merge({ for l in local.lolom[0] : l.name => l.port }, { monitor = local.monitor })
```

1. It will go through the first list of maps as denoted by `for l in local.lolom[0]`
2. Then it will set the name of the map equal to the port's value returning a map itself so now we have `{ https = 30443, http = 30080 }`
3. The `merge()` will then combine our map with the `monitor` map to give us our intended result

   ```
   {
     "http"    = "30080"
     "https"   = "30443"
     "monitor" = "30012"
   }
   ```

I couldn't find a way to convert the above into the arguments without using `jsonencode` but the following seems to provide the intended result.

```hcl
locals {
  lolom = [
    [
      { name : "https", port : 30443 },
      { name : "http", port : 30080 }
    ],
    [
      { name : "https", port : 30443 },
      { port : 30080, name : "http" }
    ]
  ]

  monitor = 30012

  first  = merge({ for l in local.lolom[0] : l.name => l.port }, { monitor = local.monitor })
  second = merge({ for l in local.lolom[1] : l.name => l.port }, { monitor = local.monitor })

  first_args  = replace(jsonencode(local.first), "/[\\{\\}\"\\s]/", "")
  second_args = replace(jsonencode(local.second), "/[\\{\\}\"\\s]/", "")
}

output "first_args" {
  value = local.first_args
}

output "second_args" {
  value = local.second_args
}
```

Apply

```sh
$ terraform apply

Apply complete! Resources: 0 added, 0 changed, 0 destroyed.

Outputs:

first_args = http:30080,https:30443,monitor:30012
second_args = http:30080,https:30443,monitor:30012
```